# Hide selected option from other dropdown if multiple dropdowns are bind with same data source

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I need to create multiple mat-select within `*ngFor` and bind it with the same data source. My requirement is that if an option is selected from any dropdown then it should not present in the rest of the dropdowns. I have a code like this.

```html
<div *ngFor="let investment of data.priorInvestmentExperiences; let i=index;">
  <mat-form-field appearance=" outline " class="mat-type">
    <mat-label><strong> Investment Type </strong> </mat-label>
    <mat-select
      [(value)]="investment.productTypeCode"
      (click)="click($event)"
      (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event, i)"
    >
      <mat-option *ngFor="let type of  getSerialNumbers(i)" [value]="type.code">
        {{type.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

and in ts file...

```js
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  InvestmentTypes = [
    {
      code: 1,
      name: "invesmentType1",
    },
    {
      code: 2,
      name: "invesmentType2",
    },
    {
      code: 3,
      name: "invesmentType3",
    },
    {
      code: 4,
      name: "invesmentType4",
    },
  ];
  data = {
    priorInvestmentExperiences: [
      {
        productTypeCode: 1,
      },
      {
        productTypeCode: 2,
      },
      {
        productTypeCode: 3,
      },
      {
        productTypeCode: 4,
      },
    ],
  };
  arrSelection: Array<KeyValuePair> = new Array<KeyValuePair>();
  ischanged = false;
  click(event) {
    return false;
  }
  selectionChange(event, itemIndex) {
    const selectedVal = event.value;
    let cc: KeyValuePair = {
      key: selectedVal,
      value: itemIndex,
    };
    this.arrSelection.push(cc);
    this.ischanged = true;
  }

  getData(itemIndex) {
    const filteredList = this.InvestmentTypes;

    if (
      this.arrSelection.length > 0 &&
      this.arrSelection.filter((x) => x.value === itemIndex).length >= 0
    ) {
      this.InvestmentTypes.forEach((sn) => {
        if (this.arrSelection[sn.code] !== itemIndex) {
          filteredList.push(sn);
        }
      });
    } else {
    }
    return filteredList;
  }
}

export interface KeyValuePair {
  key: any;
  value: any;
}
```

But is stuck within `getData()`. I need to change the data source of mat options on mat-select change but after changing data it got stuck in the `getData` method. Any suggestions, please.

Comment: here is a similar one, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pgfkn6

Comment: Yes, but the problem is my dropdowns are within loop and need to bind it with same datasource and alter that datasource.

Comment: i think it's not right to use same source for the multipe selections

Comment: can you update the stackblitz with your code? i can put something there